# How to use LinqToSql to select columns AS

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Hi I have a user control that has a repeater that is bound to one of two tables dependant on a parameter set in user control. The two tables have similar data so in past I have used a SQL connection and got the data as such..

```
If m_Type = "STD" Then
   'Type is Standard so get data from S_Updates
   SQL="SELECT S_USER as User, S_Date as UDate, S_Update as Update FROM S_Updates WHERE S_Ref = " & m_caseRef & " ORDER By S_Date"
Else
   'Type is BSM so get data from B_Updates
   SQL="SELECT B_Device as User, B_Date as UDate, B_Update as Update FROM B_Updates WHERE B_Ref = " & m_caseRef & " ORDER By B_Date"
End If
```

I would then bind the result to my repeater that has a layout with three databound containers with the following syntax

```
<%= DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UDate" %>
<%= DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "User" %>
<%= DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Update" %>
```

I have now been asked to change the code so that it uses LinqToSql

I have the following which will select from S_Updates

```
Dim CaseUpdate = From u in dc.S_Updates
                 Where u.S_Ref = m_CaseRef
                 Order By u.S_Date
                 Select u
```

How do I change this so that I get...

```
CaseUpdate.UDate instead of CaseUpdate.S_Date, 
CaseUpdate.User instead of CaseUpdate.S_User and
CaseUpdate.Update instead of CaseUpdate.S_Update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok worked it out....

```
Dim CaseUpdate = From u in dc.S_Updates
                 Where u.S_Ref = m_CaseRef
                 Order By u.S_Date
                 Select New With {.UDate = u.S_Date,
                                  .User = u.S_User,
                                  .Update = u.S_Update}
```